# Column Store Indexes in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, indexing, columnstore

Are **column store indexes** in SQL Server useful only when the query uses aggregate functions?

Comment: Google to understand what columnstore index is.

Answer (score 1):

Certainly no. Even if they were designed to be used in `DWH` ambient, they can be used in `OLTP` environment.

And even when used in `DWH`, aggregation is not a requirenment.

> Columnstore indexes use a different storage format for data, **storing
>   compressed data on a per-column  rather than a per-row basis**. This
>   storage format benefits query processing in data warehousing,
>   reporting,  and analytics environments where, although they typically
>   read a very large number of rows, queries work  with just a subset of
>   the columns from a table.

So the first benefit is data compression.

**Compression** in columnstore is table-wide, non page-wide (I mean dictionary applied) when you use PAGE data compression. So the compression ratio is the best. A table with clustered columnstore index defined uses less space compared to the same table with no columnstore but page compression enambed.

The second benefit is for queries that filter nothing(or almost nothing, needing (almost) all the rows) but need **only some columns to be returned**.

When the table is stored "per-row", even if you want only 10 columns of 100, and you want all the rows, the whole table will be read, because there is a need to read the whole row to get your 10 requested columns out of it. When you use "per-column" storage, only needed columns will be read.

Of course you can define an index with your 10 needed columns as included, but it will be additional space used and the overhead of maintenance of this index. Now imagin that your queries need these 10, and other 10, and another 2o of 100, so you need to create more indexes for these queries.

With one columnstore index you will be able to satisfy all these queries

Answer (score 0):

Columnstore Indexes, stores data in columnar format, therefore they are quite helpful when you are using aggregate functions. One of the reason is, because homogeneous data compression is much faster when you are trying to aggregate columns.

But this is not the only use of columnstore indexes. It is really helpful when you are processing millions of rows (in multidimensional data models).
Check out the [official documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg492088(v=sql.120).aspx)   and [this](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/database-administration/columnstore-indexes-in-sql-server-2012/) as well for better understanding.

Answer (score 0):

You can't say they are `always` useful for aggregate functions as it depends on which rows are included in the aggregation. If you are performing aggregation on all rows - they are useful. If you are selecting only small amount of the rows because of filtering, you can even get worse result than using traditional non-clustered index.

As it is written in [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/columnstore-indexes-overview), they can be used:

- to achieve up to 10x query performance gains in your data warehouse
  over traditional row-oriented storage
- to get 10x data compression over the uncompressed data size (if you are interested in compression in should check the `COLUMNSTORE_ARCHIVE` option)

Also, depending on your SQL Server version (if SQL Server 2017 or later) you can check the [Adaptive Query Processing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/adaptive-query-processing) as one of the conditions is to have such index:

[image]

You should look through the documentation and see what options you have depending on your SQL Server version and to test for sure how this index is going to affect the performance, because it is very possible to make the things worse.

It's good that in every article Microsoft have mention the scenarios when the types of column store indexes can be used for good.